# Trying to implement search in recycler view

Tags: java, android, search, android-recyclerview

I have spent about two days on it but cant find the error. everything else is working but when i search something it does not show anything.

this is my adapter class for volley

```
    public class GethubAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GethubAdapter.GethubViewHolder> implements Filterable {
    private List<User> userListFull;
    private List<User> userList;


    private Context context;

    public GethubAdapter(Context context, List<User> userList) {

        this.context = context;
        this.userList = userList;
        userListFull= new ArrayList<>(userList);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public GethubViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_user_layout2, parent, false);
        return new GethubViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull GethubViewHolder holder, int position) {
        User user = userList.get(position);

        holder.label.setText(user.getAvatarUrl());
        holder.value.setText(String.valueOf(user.getId()));
        holder.unit.setText(user.getFollowersUrl());
        //Glide.with(holder.imageView.getContext()).load(user.getAvatarUrl()).into(holder.imageView);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return userList.size();
    }

    public class GethubViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


        TextView label, value, unit;

        public GethubViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            label = itemView.findViewById(R.id.label);
            value = itemView.findViewById(R.id.value);
            unit = itemView.findViewById(R.id.unit);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return userFilter;
    }
    private Filter userFilter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            List<User> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

            if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                filteredList.addAll(userListFull);
            } else {
                String filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();

                for (User item : userListFull) {
                    if (item.getId().toString().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)) {
                        filteredList.add(item);
                    }
                }
            }

            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            results.values = filteredList;
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            userList.clear();
            userListFull.addAll((List) results.values);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}
```

this is my main activity class where i am using gson to convert jason objects into java objects

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //private static final String URL = "http://192.168.18.18:1880/mac/user/data.json";
    private static final String URL = "https://api.github.com/users";
    List<User> light;
    GethubAdapter adapter;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.userList);
        light = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new GethubAdapter(this, light);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d("code", response);
                GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
                Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
                //light = (List<User>) gson.fromJson(response,User.class);
                List<User> items = new Gson().fromJson(response, new TypeToken<List<User>>() {
                }.getType());
                Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<User>>() {
                }.getType();
                List<User> light = new Gson().fromJson(response, listType);
                adapter = new GethubAdapter(MainActivity.this, light);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,user[0].getBody(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        queue.add(request);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.example_menu, menu);

        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();

        searchView.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

                adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                return false;
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
}
```

i am using volley library for getting data from api

Comment: If my answer helped , please upvote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here :

```
 protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        userList.clear();
        userListFull.addAll((List) results.values);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

You have not updated userlist . Update there , it will work like :

```
protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        userList.clear();
        userList.addAll((List) results.values);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```